# Entering text into a textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a form:

```
function show_welcome()
{
        print_r($_REQUEST);
        global $error_flag , $date_error_flag;      

        $first_name = isset($_REQUEST['Fname']) ? $_REQUEST['Fname'] : "";
        $last_name = isset($_REQUEST["Lname"]) ? $_REQUEST["Lname"] : "";
        $phone = isset($_REQUEST["Phone"]) ? $_REQUEST["Phone"] : "";
        $height = isset($_REQUEST["Height"]) ? $_REQUEST["Height"] : "";
        $birthday = isset($_REQUEST["Bday"]) ? $_REQUEST["Bday"] : "";
        $sex = isset($_REQUEST["Sex"]) ? $_REQUEST["Sex"] : "";
        $history = isset($_REQUEST["Hx"]) ? $_REQUEST["Hx"] : "";
        $age = isset($_REQUEST["Age"]) ? $_REQUEST["Age"] : "";
?>                
        <form method='post' action=""  > 
    <center> 
            First Name: <input type='text' name='Fname' maxlength = '10' value = <?php echo $first_name ?> ></input>
            Last  Name: <input type='text' name='Lname' maxlength = '20' size = '25' value = <?php echo $last_name ?> ></input><br /> 

   </center>
   <div id="I1">Ten Characters</div>  <div id="I2"> Twenty Characters</div><br /><br /> 
    <center>        
        Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone" value = <?php echo $phone ?> ></input>
        Height: <input type="text" name="Height" value = <?php echo $height ?> ></input><br ></center>
        <div id="I3">XXX-XXX-XXXX</div>  <div id= "I4">  Inches</div><br /><br />
        <center>Birthday: <input type='text' name='Bday'  value = <?php echo $birthday  ?> ></input><br />  


<?php   
        printf(" \t\t\t\t YYYY-MM-DD   \n\n"); 
?>  
        <p ><input type="radio" name="Sex" value = <?php echo $sex ?> value = "0"/>Male
        <input type="radio" name="Sex" value = <?php echo $sex ?> value = "1"/>Female  </p >
        Hx: <br /> 
        <textarea style="overflow: scroll" cols="60" rows="10" wrap="hard" name="Hx" value = <?php echo $history ?>   ></textarea> <p />
        <input type="text" hidden="true" name="Age" ></input>
        <br /><br /><input type="submit" />
        <br /><br /><input type = "reset" value="Clear Form"/></center>
        <input type=hidden name='welcome_already_seen'   value='already_seen'>
        </form>
<?php       

}
```

The form is filled out by the user and then checked for valid format.  Invalid format triggers an error message and the script returns to the form.  I wish to show all the data entered, so that the user can more easily make corrections.  Everything is re-entered into the form except the history (Hx).

The $_REQUEST contains the history:

Array ( [Fname] => 44444444 [Lname] => Jones [Phone] => 123-123-4656 [Height] => 62 [Bday] => 1989-03-05 [Sex] => 0 [Hx] => good pt [Age] => [welcome_already_seen] => already_seen )

As an side issue, how can I ensure that the correct radio buttons are re-checked at data re-entry.

Advice and help, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Contents of a `<textarea>` are placed within the start and end tags - There is no `value` attribute of a `<textarea>`.

```
<textarea style="overflow: scroll" cols="60" rows="10" wrap="hard" name="Hx"><?php echo $history ?></textarea>
```

You should also be careful, as `$history` can contain HTML that would open your site up to security vulnerabilities.

Radio buttons require the `` `checked="checked" `` attribute in order to be checked by default. You'd achieve this like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="Sex" value="1" <?php echo ($sex == 1 ) ? 'checked="checked" : ''; ?> />
```

Comment: This works beautifully: <?php echo ($sex == 1 ) ? 'checked="checked" : ''; ?>

Comment: This <?php echo $history ?> in the textarea string does not work.  Inserted as <textarea>  <?php echo $history ?> </textarea> and it works.